# Форма второго лица множественного числа будущего времени глагола "проложить"

Tags: морфология, глаголы

Какое написание является правильным для второго лица  множественного числа глагола "проложить"? "Проложите" или "проложете"?

Например, во фразе "вы сами проложи(е)те тропинку" (в смысле "вы сами это сделаете").

Comment: http://udarenieru.ru/index.php?doc=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Он – пролож**и**т, а вы, соответственно, пролож**и**те.

Answer (score 2):

Проложить – глагол на ИТЬ  2-го спряжения, **он  пролОжит, вы пролОжите** (2 лицо, мн. число, будущее время).

**Обратите внимание на ударение.**

Повелительное наклонение (для сравнения): проложИте.

У Зализняка: [ПРОЛОЖИТЬ | classes.ru](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-synonyms-term-69101.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Это глагол второго спряжения, поэтому в суффиксе всегда И (кроме форм 1-го лица ед. числа и 3-го множественного).

*Вы сами прол**о**жите* (вы это сделаете, будущее время)
Но: *вы сами пролож**и**те* (сделайте это, повелительное наклонение)